# 他のDockerコンテナからコンテナ内のMySQL/MariaDBに接続したい

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

docker-composeを使ってコンテナオーケストレーションを学んでいます。

以下のフォルダ構成で、appコンテナから、dbコンテナのmariadbにアクセスしたいのですが、エラーが出てうまくいきません。

### ディレクトリ構成

```
.
├── app
│   └── Dockerfile
├── db
│   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

### コード

app/Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
        mariadb-client \
        vim

CMD [ "tail", "-f" ]
```

db/Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
        mariadb-server \
        mariadb-client \
        vim

CMD service mysql start \
    && tail -f /dev/null
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend

  db:
    build: ./db
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

### 実行コマンド

appコンテナに入って、以下のコマンドを実行しましたが、エラーが出ます。

```sh
root@0e0ad0889639:/# mysql -h db -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)

## 接続は出来ているようです。
root@0e0ad0889639:/# ping db
PING db (192.168.128.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from test_db_1.test_frontend (192.168.128.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from test_db_1.test_frontend (192.168.128.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
```

コンテナが接続できない理由を教えて頂きたいです。よろしくお願いします。

### 試したこと

#### dbコンテナ側

dbコンテナは初期設定等は行っていないです。
dbのコンテナでmariadbを立ち上げる事はできます。

```
root@9d3b519e464f:/# service --status-all
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  mysql
 [ - ]  rsync
```

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------+-----------+
| User | Host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
```

#### appのコンテナ側

コンテナ名を返るとエラーが変わるので、通信自体は出来ていそうです。

```
root@69ccb34f8a30:/# mariadb -u root -h db
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)

root@69ccb34f8a30:/# mariadb -u root -h aa
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'aa' (-2)
```

### 環境

```sh
❯ docker -v        
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
❯ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.3
BuildVersion:   21E230
```

Comment: db コンテナ側に入った場合は DB にログインは出来ている状態ですか？ / デーモンの起動こそしているものの、何も設定をしていないように見えるのが気になります。

Comment: @cubick さん
ありがとうございます。試したことを追記しました。初期設定等は行っておりません。初期設定を行っていない場合は、外部のコンテナからアクセスできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

2つの設定を変えることで解決しました。

① mysql内部での受け入れホストの設定

```
USE mysql;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' identified by 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
```

② mysqlのconfigファイルの変更

etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
に以下を追記です。
bind-address = app